# Android layout - alignment issue with ImageView

Tags: android, layout, android-imageview

I'm trying to put an image at the top left of a `LinearLayout`, but with the image border and padding taking up the whole of the width of the window.

If I try the XML below, I get my image with its border and a white background across the whole width of the page, *except* that the image ends up **centered**, and doesn't move to the left.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/banner"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/d_8px"
/>
```

Is there some attribute that I've not yet discovered that forces the image to be left aligned within the `ImageView` when the `layout_width` is set to `fill_parent`?

In the meantime, I've worked around this by dropping the `ImageView` inside another `LinearLayout` and dropping an empty `TextView` to its right that takes up the rest of the horizontal space.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I was having a similar problem, to which you replied earlier today. Is this on "screen design" viewer provided by the Eclipse plugin side-by-side with the XML editor, or are you encountering the alignment problems when actually running the app? If the former, that appers to be a bug in the plugin, if the latter, try adding:

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

From the documentation I've read, that seems to be the closest to what you need.

Comment: that does indeed seem to do the trick.  As does not using an ImageView at all and using the drawableLeft attribute of a TextView :)

Comment: Thanks... worked great and saved me the time of asking this question myself

Comment: fitEnd will get it to sit at the bottom... which was MY conundrum in the same family of stuff not working as expected

Comment: I had an imageview which just didn't want to achknowledge alignparentleft but with fitstart it did =/

Comment: Perfect solution dude! Works correctly with Samsung Galaxy S3 and Panasonic JT-B1

Answer (score 8):

Just configure your ImageView on your layout XML file with something like this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageViewName" 
    android:layout_width="90dp" 
    android:layout_height="90dp" 
    android:scaleType="fitStart" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```