# Android ImageButton -- can't get image in the center

Tags: xml, android, layout, imagebutton

I want to create an Android ImageButton in the xml file with a background image, and a smaller icon on top of that, right in the center. For some reason, it's not obvious how to do it, and documentation is no help.

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/sound_button"
android:layout_x="430px"
android:layout_y="219px"
android:layout_width="48px"
android:layout_height="48px"
android:scaleType="center"
android:src="@android:drawable/volumeicon"
android:background="@drawable/clearbuttonup"
/>
```

However, no matter what I try (putting "**wrap _ content**" instead of **absolute** numbers on layout _ height and layout _ width, the icon remains in the top left corner of the button. If, however, I have no background image (i.e. a system default white button), the icon does go into the center. The button also goes into the top left corner when I use a color instead of an image for the background.

Why does this happen, and how would I actually get the behavior I want-- that is, a background image with the icon in the center?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm a real moron. That's how it appears in the display the Ecliplse plugin provide side-by-side with the XML editor. When I actually build the project and ran it on a device, it displayed everything correctly.

Comment: I had this experience too... fretted over it for ages then tried it out on my phone and it displayed fine. I wonder where we can report these bugs.

Comment: "Ecliplse plugin provide side-by-side with the XML editor." are you saying that the Eclipse plugin has a designer in the IDE? Have I missed something

Answer (score 1):

Ironically I had exactly the opposite problem with an ImageView - I couldn't get it left-aligned no matter what I tried.  In this case I was using `layout_width="fill_parent"`.

See my question here: [Android layout - alignment issue with ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655994/android-layout-alignment-issue-with-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

try use the Button and set the background it's very useful and easy :D

make the text empty and you can use it like image button ^_^