# Need help in Dashboard in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, dashboard

I have created dashboard for my app. In that I added search button also. I wish to align this button to right side but for that i don't want to use the margin. I have added the image of my layout + code.

**UPDATED**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout style="@style/TitleBar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        style="@style/TitleBarLogo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/titlebar"
        android:contentDescription="Logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <ImageView
        style="@style/TitleBarSeparator"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        style="@style/TitleBarAction"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="Searching..."
        android:onClick="onClickSearch"
        android:src="@drawable/title_search" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/titlebar"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature1"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature2"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button2"                    
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature3"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button3"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home_btn_feature4"
                style="@style/HomeButton"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_button4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATED**

styles.xml

```
<style name="TitleBar">
        <item name="android:id">@id/titlebar</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarLogo">
        <item name="android:id">@id/title_logo</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarAction">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/title_button</item>
    </style>
<style name="TitleBarSeparator">
        <item name="android:layout_width">1px</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/title_separator</item>
    </style>
```

[image: OLD]

[image: NEW UPDATED]

**UPDATED MY CODE AND JUST ONE STEP TO COMPLETE IT. THE SEPERATOR IS SOME HOW NOT VISIBLE.**

If anyone has any idea please kindly help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<ImageButton
        style="@style/TitleBarAction"
        android:contentDescription="Searching..."
        android:onClick="onClickSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/title_search" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but still same result. And layout_alignParentRight is also not suggested....

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead LinearLayout

Comment: actually i tried with relative layout also. but when i use it everything just go here and there. I am working on Relative layout. If you have any suggestion for that please let me know. I have posted the whole dashboard layout here.

Comment: Please see my update code. I used RelativeLayout and almost to achieve what i wish. Only Separator is not visible. If you have any idea please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would recommend looking into using the [Action Bar](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) if at all possible,

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

should work, you could also acheive what you want by making you `TitleBarLogo` and magnifying glass graphic [a 9-patch image](https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) that leaves the middle blank and resizes automatically without distorting the graphic.

Comment: I have added my styles.xml code. And i try layout_alignParentRight="true" but not working.

Comment: In addition to `alignParentRight` in the `ImageView` have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655994/android-layout-alignment-issue-with-imageview ? `android:scaleType="fitStart"`

Comment: Sorry, I was editing that above comment quite a bit. As appserv says I would recommend using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and then you can use `android:gravity="right"` here is an example https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-beginners/VnBse3k5MiA

Comment: @Prem for `RelativeLayout` just replace all your `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` and then in `ImageButton` try `android:gravity="right"`

Comment: I have used RelativeLayout and i am almost there to achieve it. The seperator is some how not visible. Please just see my updated code...

Comment: maybe try `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content` for the `TitleBarSeperator` `layout_height`

Comment: Maybe add padding? `android:paddingLeft="5dp"`