# Placing image in Left side in ImageView, in case ImageView takes full width of screen?

Tags: android

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/nextarrow_final"
/>
```

I want this image to be on the left side.

Any help??

Comment: android:gravity="left"

Comment: put imgaeview into Linearlayout vertical with same parameter  at set Gravity of linear layout to left , set Imageview parameter to wrap content

Comment: try this android:scaleType="fitStart" reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655994/android-layout-alignment-issue-with-imageview

Comment: @AmolTate : android:gravity="left" does not work on ImageView.

Comment: use layout_gravity="left"

Comment: post image what you want.

Answer (score 7):

@Anish Mittal

Here I am Describe your problem solution in both layout :

1> **Linear Layout**

This code put inside Main Linear Layout

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/learlayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

2> **Relative Layout**

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

This Code Is Multi screen Supported Also....!!!

Comment: hahahaha. What I said above. I want to keep width as fill_parent. And you make parent width as "wrap_content".

Comment: I know your question but if you have some space on right side of image this task is full fill

Comment: android:scaleType="fitStart" works for me in case of android:layout_width="match_parent" !

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your layout. (android:scaleType="fitStart")

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorDefaultBg">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:id="@+id/image_logo"
            android:src="@drawable/my_logo" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text=""
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


     <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/nextarrow_final"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Because you've your image width as "fill_parent" do you want your image width to cover the full screen ? if no then try putting some pixels eg. android:layout_width="80dp" rather than using "fill_parent".

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned width as "fill parent". So, it takes full width instead give "wrap content" for both width and height inside Linear Layout it align left. I thinks it helps you.

Comment: I know this. But I want to keep width "fill_parent" and inside that , sifting small image left.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Add this in your Code:

```
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY );
```

Comment: ScaleType.FIT_XY will not work. Rather ScaleType fitStart works. :)